# Maximum value in a selected column

Tags: python, pandas

I have DataFrame I'd like to find a maximum value in

```
       r        A1            r2      
0   1.300059  1.169174e+01    0.904864   
1   0.869749  4.389630e+01    2.2838
2   7.258726  3.105024e+00    4.8423276  
3   1.462826  2.118224e+10    0.847984   
4  45.823676  1.130893e+06    0.82377
```

For example for r2 I want to print out: 4.8423276.

I've tried use df['r2'].max(), but it returns an index instead of a value,

Comment: `df.['r2'].max()` shouldn't even work given it is incorrect syntax

Comment: Hm, `idxmax()` would return an index, not `max()`. I cannot reproduce your issue.

Comment: Either use df.r2.max() or df['r2'].max()

Comment: Check the type of `r2` column.

Comment: @Yakym Pirozhenko and  bernie. The type was string that's the reason I was getting a problem. Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

You can try:

```
max([ i['r2'] for i in df ])
min([ i['r2'] for i in df ])
```

Comment: I am not sure what you are trying to return here, but I don't think it works. For example, df = pd.DataFrame({'a':[1,2,3,5,4], 'b':[0,1,2,0,0]})
max([i['a'] for i in df]) will throw an error.